# VS 2017 MakePri errors

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, visual-studio-2017

Since I migrated to Visual Studio 2017, I have the following compilation errors:

For the main project:

> MakePri : error 0x80070002: Processing Resources failed with error: Le fichier spécifié est introuvable

For a dependency project:

> MakePRI : error 0xdef00071: File C:[project_path]\bin\Debug[project_name].pri not found.

I use exactly the same project with no updates since the last success build on Visual Studio 2015

Note: this is a project that targets the Windows 10 IoT platform

Thanks

Samuel

Comment: try cleaning the solution and then deleting the 'bin' and 'obj' folders, restart VS and rebuild. I think this will fix it.

Comment: I already tried this. So I re-tried to do it in the same order you suggest but I still have the same issue

Comment: I've had the same, it's quite persistent, but Rafael's solution (plus dancing round clockwise three times) eventually does the trick.

Comment: I tried to copy the solution to an other PC executed the same version of Visual Studio 2017 and I have the same error...

Comment: Can you send me an email at dajaco at microsoft dot com and we can try to figure out what is going on?

Comment: Did you try to manually run the commands go generate those files?